# Use type definition of similiar package

Tags: typescript, typescript-typings

I'm using [fabric-with-gestures](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fabric-with-gestures) in my Typescript application and everything is fine.
However, the original library [fabric](https://www.npmjs.com/package/fabric) has types defined and I can install them with `npm install --dev @types/fabric` but Typescript doesn't recognize them for the `fabric-with-gestures` package.

How could I use the typings from `fabric` together with `fabric-with-gestures` as there is no module `@types/fabric-with-gestures` and I'm assuming that the types are mostly the same? 
Is this even possible?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

For all packages in general, you can create a type alias by adding [`baseUrl`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#base-url) and [`paths`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/module-resolution.html#path-mapping) options to your [tsconfig.json](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/tsconfig-json.html) (I don't use `fabric`, but a quick setup just did compile successfully).

tsconfig.json:

```
{
  "compilerOptions": {
    ...
    // absolute name imports are resolved relative to baseUrl
    "baseUrl": ".", 
    // alias "fabric-with-gestures" is mapped to path of fabric @types
    "paths": { 
      "fabric-with-gestures": ["node_modules/@types/fabric"]
    }
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
// Use fabric-with-gestures. Types are internally mapped to @types/fabric
import { fabric } from "fabric-with-gestures";
```